# Почему не функционирует @fontface?

Tags: css3, css

Здравствуйте!
Делаю сайт для дочки - www.симультики.рф. Подскажите, почему у меня не функционирует стандартный вроде бы набор css-правил для fontface:

```
@font-face {
   font-family: 'cassandraregular';
   src: url('cassandra-webfont.eot');
   src: url('cassandra-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
        url('cassandra-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
        url('cassandra-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
        url('cassandra-webfont.svg#cassandraregular') format('svg');
   font-weight: normal;
   font-style: normal;

}
```

взятый со всем известного генератора ([@font-face Generator](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fontface/generator))? Я ставлю данный код в файл css, копирую шрифты на сервер, что не так сделал?..

Comment: Все понятно - в генераторе надо проставить галочку на кириллице в разделе языков.

Answer (score 2):

Вы его подключили все правильно, но вы не подключили его к самому CSS т.е если у вас этот шрифт для всего сайта, то в тэг body пропишите так:

> ```
> /* body
>    ----------*/
> body {
>     font: 14px "cassandraregular", "Arial";
>     }
> ```

*Arial тут как безопасный шрифт!*
Но также не забываем прописать в CSS точный путь где лежит ваш сконвертированный шрифт
url('cassandra-webfont.eot'); - он должен содержать путь например style.css у вас в папке CSS, а шрифт отдельно в папке FONT.

```
Значит в url будет таким url('../cassandra-webfont.eot'); либо url('../../cassandra-webfont.eot');
```

Comment: А обязательно прописывать именно в боди? Я например прописываю данный шрифт только для заголовков. Правильный путь вроде прописал - шрифты закинул в корневую, а путь указал просто 'cassandra-webfont.eot' и т.д., не сработало(...

Comment: конечно не обязательно, все зависит от того где именно вы будете применять тот или иной шрифт. я привел как пример.

Comment: ну, я прописал для заголовков font-family: 'cassandraregular', serif;, что ж не работает-то?..

Comment: быть может от того что путь не правильный? откройте firebug наведите на ваш заголовок и посмотрите подгрузился ли у вас шрифт в CSS

Comment: Странно, но нет, не подгрузился! Я уже чего только не делал, и полный путь типа http://www.симультики.рф/css/ прописывал и в корень клал, что ж такое?!

Comment: такс как бы вам помочь то, но путь точно не так прописывать. мой скайп nosensus добавьте меня поговорим.

Comment: Попробуйте набить фаш заголовок на английском или добавить цифру. Я спотыкался пару раз о проблему отсутствия кириллициы в шрифте.

Comment: Да, на английском все нормально. Но проблема в том, что шрифт-то чисто русский, на локалке он нормально отображается на русском, а на сайте почему-то нет, в чем тут может быть дело?

Comment: Очень странно. Если у вас отображается все, кроме кириллических символов, то беда, наверняка, в самом шрифте.

Comment: А что касается различий между локальной версией и версией на хостинге, то мне в голову приходит только две возможные проблемы, с которыми я сталкивался. 1) Сбитые пути/папки. 2) Символ точки в названии папки - на локалке у меня игнорировался и все было норм. На хостинге точка засчитывалась в имя и путь был неверный.

Answer (score 0):

[@font-face Generator](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fontface/generator) - генератор хороший, но с кириллицей у него действительно пробоемки бывают. Попробуйте использовать [вот этот генератор](http://www.font2web.com/), в 99% таких случаев, он меня выручал.

Comment: в генераторе надо выбрать экспертный режим и проставить галочку на кириллице в разделе языков и все решается

Comment: Нет, не "все решается". Если бы я с данной проблемой не сталкивался, то не писал бы.

Comment: ну незнаю, смотрю на browsershots, все везде вроде бы нормально, а какие у вас проблемы?

Comment: > ... а какие у вас проблемы?
@Aviko, у меня? ))) Сейчас много проблем, напр., правительство, дураки и дороги )) А с шрифтами - уже давно проблем нет

Answer (score 0):

Я понимаю, что это уже не актуально, но поисковики при проблемах со шрифтами выкидывают на эту страницу. Поэтому решил добавить.

Вот [инструкция](http://web-sputnik.info/html-css/20), что надо сделать вот в этом [генераторе шрифтов](https://www.fontsquirrel.com/tools/webfont-generator) для корректного отображения кириллицы. Так же нужно проследить за правильностью размещением файлов и пути в css к ним.

Comment: добро пожаловать на [ru.so]! здесь принято давать **полный** ответ, а ссылки приводить лишь в качестве дополнения/иллюстрации.